# Calculate maximum allowed current of a cable with AWG, length, and voltage?

Tags: current, cables

How can I estimate the maximum current of a cable with thickness, length, and the voltage? Assuming that the material is cheap aluminium, not expensive copper, and in room temperature.

For example, the seller does not specify how much current that this cable allows, and all the page says is AWG22 and 30cm. I want to know if this cable is suitable for a 5V 3A charger and a device that can consume 5V 3.5A theoretically.

[image]

Comment: There is no cable that can fix a 3A charger driving a 3.5A load.

Comment: @user_1818839 you don't know "the device", it may operate differently when it's charging.

Comment: @SimSon then the question needs some clarification.

Comment: The wires in that cable will be copper - the "silvery" color of the conductors is solder.

Comment: @user_1818839 What do you mean by "fix"? The charger is rated at 5V3A (says the manufacturer), and the device is a 7-port USB 2.0 hub. The maximum current of a USB 2.0 port is said to be 0.5A. So, 7*0.5A = 3.5A. By "there is no such cable", you mean this providing 5V3A to the hub is not possible?

Comment: No, I mean that you can't provide 3.5A to the hub, from a 3A supply. Given the further information that should have been in the question, leave 1 of 7 ports empty and you should be fine. (Or ensure that some of the other ports draw much less than 0.5A)

Comment: @user_1818839 The maximum current that the hub may consume is 3.5A, but of course, I wanted to supply 3A with a 5V3A charger (Not all USB devices needs 0.5A all the time, so even if I use all 7 ports at the same time, I think it is very unlikely or rare that the hub would need more than 3A). So, you think that the cable can handle 5V3A, huh?

Answer (score 1):

A 30 cm piece of AWG22 aluminium cable has a resistance of ~25 mΩ, dissipating around 300 mW at 3.5 A.
This should be fine in free air.

The cable will drop ~100 mV.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say there is no simple answer to your question there is more information needed. What are the temperature limits, environment etc. I use a calculator, there are many online. This one does the smaller gauges but does not answer all of your questins. https://www.inchcalculator.com/voltage-drop-calculator/
There are other calculators that will also do the temperatures etc. You state the cable but what is between it and the battery. How much time do you have to charge the battery? What type of battery and what chemistry. The calculator shows using your information and aluminum cable.
Voltage Drop:
voltage drop:   0.2274 volts
voltage drop percent:   4.547%
voltage at the end of the circuit:  4.773 volts

Comment: The charger is rated at 5V3A (says the manufacturer), and the device is a 7-port USB 2.0 hub. The maximum current of a USB 2.0 port is said to be 0.5A. So, 7*0.5A = 3.5A. It is unlikely that I would connect 7 highly-power consuming USB devices at the same time, but just in case, I thought of choosing a cable that can handle 5V3A.